# Can ServiceWorkers cover no-src child iframe requests?

Tags: google-chrome, cross-domain, service-worker

Say I have a page with a ServiceWorker registered successfully, I can do

```
document.body.innerHTML = `<img src="some-img.jpg" />`;
```

to trigger a new request that the worker may handle. However

```
document.body.innerHTML = `<iframe></iframe>`;
document.body.firstChild.contentDocument.body.innerHTML =
        `<img src="some-img.jpg" />`;
```

will not be picked up by the worker, at least from what I can see in Chrome 49.

In my particular case, we have tests that rely on rendering an iframe and then rendering content inside the iframe for style-scoping purposes, and I was hoping that I could speed up our tests by aggressively caching resources loaded for the duration of the tests, but all the requests triggered by content inside the iframe skip the worker.

Is there any way that the iframe can be made to use the outer worker when fetching resources?

I'd assume that one option would be to have the iframe load a dummy HTML file from the server so that the iframe had the proper origin, I was just hoping I could avoid needing to change our current iframe approach to do that (and have to delay rendering until that page loaded), since it doesn't seem unreasonable for an 'about:blank'-style iframe to be treated as same-origin in cases where JS is able to reach across the frame boundary.

#### Update

I also attempted to also do

```
document.body.firstChild.contentWindow.navigator.serviceWorker.register(...)
```

with the same worker used in the outer window, however that results in

> DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: No URL is associated with the caller's document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=439697) (although interestingly Firefox has the same behavior).

(And contrary to my previous suggestion, you shouldn't need to explicitly register the service worker in the iframe.)

Comment: Ahh thank's for tracking that down. It seemed like a bug, but I wasn't 100% sure yet.

Comment: Just to clarify. This bug is still around in chrome75 and the bug tracker doesnt seem to point at any resolution

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=880768